# GPU monitoring software

Tags: monitoring, gpu

I'm interested in a GPU monitoring software that would log the processes and the memory (video card memory) being used by the processes.

I'm opened to all kind of solutions, even a software + some scripts to help me log this kind of data.

I need the software to run under Windows Vista

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158712/monitor-the-graphics-card-usage

Answer (score 1):

[Nvidia perfkit](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nvperfkit_home.html) will help you. It won't work with ATI GPUs though.